# Error "non-static method should not be called statically" usando clases

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con clases PHP y me da el siguiente error:

> Deprecated: Non-static method ConexionBD::cBD() should not be called statically in C:\wamp64\www\ExClinic\Modelos\EmpleadosM.php on line 5

Revisando la línea 5 del código tengo lo siguiente:

```
$pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT usuario, clave, nombre, apellido, foto, rol, id FROM $tablaBD
        WHERE usuario = :usuario");
```

Aquí esta el código completo:

```
<?php
require_once "ConexionBD.php";
class EmpleadosM extends ConexionBD{
    public static function IngresarEmpleadoM($tablaBD, $datosC){
        
        $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT usuario, clave, nombre, apellido, foto, rol, id FROM $tablaBD
        WHERE usuario = :usuario");

        $pdo -> bindParam(":usuario", $datosC["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $pdo -> execute();

        return $pdo -> fetch();

        $pdo -> close();

        $pdo = null;


    }
}
```

Estuve investigando, pero me atoré y llevo toda la tarde.

Estoy empezando con PHP y me gustaría saber a qué puede deberse este error.

Comment: Tal y como dice el mensaje de error, el método `cBD()` de la clase `ConexionBD` no es estático, por lo que no deberías llamarlo haciendo uso de los dos puntos (`::`), si no creando una instancia con `new` y posteriormente llamando a dicho método o, alternativamente, cambiar el método a estático ('static`).

Comment: Por cierto, todo lo que tienes detrás del `return $pdo -> fetch();` no se ejecutará nunca, ya que el `return` devuelve el control al código llamante. Deberías liberar los recursos **antes** de devolver el resultado (y no, no deberías hacer un `$pdo = null;` hasta haber terminado de trabajar con los registros obtenidos).

Comment: Thx, ya vi el mi error, volveré a darle una revisada, creo que esto tiene que ver con la versión, estaré repasando mejor tutoriales mas actualizados, muchas gracias!